# How to remove a record without destroying it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using Mongoid and I have 2 models, Flow and Node with a referenced parent-child relationship.

```
class Node
  belongs_to :flow
end

class Flow
  has_many :nodes
end
```

When I want to remove a node with a flow I do this:

```
flow.nodes.clear
```

This destroy the associated nodes. What if I want to remove the association between the node and the flow without destroying the associated nodes? Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: `Flow` `belongs_to :flow` typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `flow.nodes.clear` as long as you don't have `:dependent => :destroy` set. From the [Rails Guide on Association Basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference):

> 4.3.1.7 collection.clear
>
> The collection.clear method removes every object from the collection.
>   This destroys the associated objects if they are associated with
>   :dependent => :destroy, deletes them directly from the database if
>   :dependent => :delete_all, **and otherwise sets their foreign keys to
>   NULL**.

If this isn't working for you, you could try this and it should remove the association:

```
flow.nodes = nil
```

### EDIT 1

If not, you'll have to create a method to remove the association manually.

```
   flow.nodes.update_all :flow_id => nil
```

Comment: collection.clear just destroy the nodes, and setting it to nil doesn't work with Mongoid unfortunately.

Comment: Guess it'll have to be done manually with update_all then. Dogbert's or my method should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any in built method for this, but you can do this:

```
Node.where(:flow_id => flow.id).update_all(:flow_id => nil)
```